# How is guild influence gained in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The official wiki lists the following as one way to get influence:

> 2 influence for individual guild members completing an event or part of a personal storyline. (The per-player influence gained increases substantially with each new participating guild member.)

Does anyone know exactly how this guild bonus works?  Does this mean if you have more than one guild member completing an event together, you each generate more influence for the guild?

**Update:** Appears that you get 20 influence if you do an event with one or more guildies together

Comment: If you open the guild interface and scroll over the influence icon, it'll tell you the various ways. These include, but are not limited to, dungeons, events, and even PvP.

Comment: @Domocus, repost this as an answer!

Comment: If I had any clue to the amount given by each event, I would. As it stands, some activities seem to grant a great deal more than others.

Comment: You can also buy influence from the Guild Promoter. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Promoter

Comment: @Brian shouldn't that edit be in the answer not the question? :P

Comment: @Gwen I edited the question title...

Comment: @Brian ah, sorry! I'm bad at wiki comparisons >_<

Answer (score 4):

According the guild wars 2 [Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Influence)

> The primary source of influence is through participation in PvE or PvP:
>
> 2  for individual guild members completing an event or part of a personal storyline. (The per-player influence gained increases substantially with each new participating guild member.)
>
> 5  for individual guild members getting a victory in a pvp match.
>
> 10  for each accepted guild invitation.
>
> 10  for each member who is online during an Attendance Check.
>
> Non-participation sources:
>
> 10  can be purchased from a Guild Promoter for  2s  (in various increments).

Answer (score 3):

If you check the history tab you can see what's being earnt.
[image]
You'll notice the 1000 there, but that's the one-time bonus you get from the consumable item.

So it seems each action is worth 2 points. Multiple members on the same quest means more points as each will earn 2 for completing the quest, event or dungeon.

Comment: Are these all dynamic events? In my own guild, not every action contributes 2 points. There's actually a fair amount that do not.

Comment: 2 inf is for events and story. It's the most prevalent means of gaining inf.